# XSLT (V 1.0) Exclude Nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a SAP IDoc and I want to remove one node if `ZGER` and `ZFER` exist then remove the parent node of `ZFER`.

Source XML:

```
<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZGER</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>

<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZFER</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>
<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZFAD</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>

<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZCDC</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>
```

Here only the values `ZGER` and `ZFER` are known.

Target:

```
<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZGER</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>  
<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZFAD</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>
<E1WPA04 SEGMENT="1">
    <KONDART>ZCDC</KONDART>
    <BEGINNZEIT>0000</BEGINNZEIT>
    <ENDDATUM>99991231</ENDDATUM>
    <ENDZEIT>0000</ENDZEIT>
</E1WPA04>
```

Comment: Cleaned up the grammar, formatted the variables to call them out. This question is still vague, imo. What have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the typical pattern based on selectively overriding an identity transformation, then the problem boils down to how do you identify the items you want to remove.  It sounds like you want to remove any `E1WPA04` element that has both

- a child `KONDART` with value `ZFER` *and*
- a sibling `E1WPA04` that has a child `KONDART` with value `ZGER`

This corresponds to

```
<xsl:template match="E1WPA04[KONDART='ZFER'][../E1WPA04/KONDART='ZGER']"/>
```

If there is *no* `ZGER` in the document then this template will not match (and so the `ZFER` will not be removed).

Comment: Hi Ian, I want to remove the whole E1WPA04 with the Child KONDART with the Value ZFER  if the Structure contains at least 2 E1WPA04 and KONDART=ZFER and KONDART=ZGER. Thanks

Comment: @Abdel that's what my template will do, if you combine it with the usual identity transformation (if you don't know what that is then search for "identity transformation xslt" on here to see hundreds of examples).  If you still can't get it working then edit your question to show the XSLT you have so far and a _well-formed_ input example (i.e. a whole document with a single root-level element) and we should be able to help you debug it.

Comment: Hello Ian, Thanks for the response. I build a transformation, that delete the parent node E1WPA04 where KONDART=ZFER and KONDART=ZGER. : <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E1WPA04[KONDART='ZFER'][../E1WPA04/KONDART='ZGER']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: but the problem is. If we don't have this condition. The Transformation should make any changes. thanks